# View Contact-Facebook connection on computer

Tags: contacts, facebook

Before I started using an Android phone, I had already connected my Google contacts with their Facebook profiles by including a URL-type field named “Facebook” with a link to their profiles.

The Android Contacts app was clever enough to link (many of) my Google contacts to their Facebook profiles, but this link seems to exist only in the phone, not in Google Contacts.

Is there a way to view & edit this aspect of my contacts database on my computer?

Comment: Isn't there anything in notes field of Google contacts on web?

Comment: Not where I can see it.